# perl6: how to specify multiple requirements for a parameter of a function?

Tags: parameters, signature, raku

I have a special function that takes a list, each member of the list must satisfy multiple requirements. How do I set this up in a perl6 function?

```
sub specialFunc(List $x) {};
```

1. $x is a list # easy, List $x, but what about the following:
2. each member of $x is numeric
3. each member of $x is positive
4. each member of $x is greater than 7
5. each member of $x is odd number
6. each member of $x is either the square or the cube of an even number plus 1;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Perl 6 type system is not flexible enough to express such constraints declaratively, but you can add a `where` clause to your parameter to check incoming arguments against a custom expression.

For clarity, I'd factor out the expression for testing each number into a `subset`:

```
subset SpecialNumber of Numeric where {
       $_ > 7                        # (3), (4)
    && $_ !%% 2                      # (5), since "odd" implies "not even"
    && .narrow ~~ Int                # (5), since "odd" implies "integer"
    && ($_ - 1) ** (1/2 | 1/3) %% 2  # (6)
}

sub specialFunc(List $x where .all ~~ SpecialNumber ) {
    ...
}
```

You could go one step further, and factor out the whole `where` clause into a `subset`:

```
subset SpecialList of List where .all ~~ SpecialNumber;

sub specialFunc(SpecialList $x) {
    ...
}
```

PS: I think your requirement (5) may be redundant, since requirement (6) seems to only satisfy odd numbers anyway, but I'm not big on number theory so I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much, smls !!! I agree, (6) implies (5) which is redundant. Thank you again !

Comment: or, you could type an Array... ```my SpecialNumber @a; sub specialFunc(SpecialNumber @a) { ... }```